# Django-like no reverse for url

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/praekelt/django-likes)

There was an error with the url so I changed it from

```
<a class="liker" href="{% url like content_type content_obj.id 1 %}" rel="nofollow">I Like</a>`
```

to

```
<a class="liker" href="{% url 'like' content_type content_obj.id 1 %}" rel="nofollow">I Like</a>
```

as recommended in [this fix](https://github.com/praekelt/django-likes/pull/9/files) but I am still getting this error

> Reverse for 'like' with arguments '(u'snippets-snippets', None, 1)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

EDIT: 
This is the urls.py from the app

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'likes.views',
    url(r'^like/(?P<content_type>[\w-]+)/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<vote>-?\d+)$', 'like',
        name='like'),
)
```

My urls.py simply includes it

```
urlpatterns = patterns('snippets.views',
    (r'^likes/', include('likes.urls')),
)
```

Comment: your `content_obj.id` is evaluating to `None` You might want to see if that object indeed exists.

Comment: you need to show us your urls.py and see if the url for 'like' is properly configured

Comment: I have edited the question to show the urls.py.

@karthikr but would that really raise an error like that?

Comment: @karthikr I tried putting a number for testing and that worked! Thanks! please put this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Supremekhaoz Added an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your error, it seems like your `content_obj.id` is evaluating to `None`.
You might want to see if that object indeed exists. If not, you might have to do a sanity check. Something like

```
{% if content_obj.id %}
    <a class="liker" href="{% url 'like' content_type content_obj.id 1 %}" rel="nofollow">I Like</a>
{% endif %}
```

Or pass the `content_obj` in the context appropriately.